# Sending data to a webpage with Post Fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, post, cookies

I am trying to send an array of guids as postdata using a javascript function. The recieving aspx page needs to process this data.

The javascript that calls the page is as following:

```
function(webadress, guidarray) {
    var params = 'menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no';
    var win = document.createElement("form");

    win.target = 'Map';
    win.method = 'POST';
    win.action = webadress;
    var winInput = document.createElement('input');
    winInput.type = 'text';
    winInput.name = 'guidcollection';
    winInput.value = guidarray;
    win.appendChild(winInput);
    win.setAttribute("target", "_blank");   
    window.open(webadress, '', params);
    win.submit();
}
```

The aspx page attempts to read the post data as following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    object PostGuids = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["guidcollection"];
    // Do something with PostGuids
}
```

Somehow it fails, and when i debug the aspx page I see that **HttpContext** is not defined. Using fiddler I can determine that the sessionId is not set. I see the message 'This request did not send any cookie data.' in the Cookies tab.

What can i do to receive the post data? One of the requirements for the website is that cookie data on the client is not allowed. Is it possible to receive Post data without a sessionId? or should i look for alternatives like ViewState? Using a query string won't work because the length of the data will exceed the 2048 character limit of a querystring.

Comment: Use Ajax? Currently you create a form then don't actually submit it, you just open a popup window (GET) There is no HTML input type of "array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working with the following changes:

```
function(webadress, guidarray) {
    var params = 'menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no';
    var win = document.createElement("form");

    win.target = 'Map';
    win.method = 'POST';
    win.action = webadress;
    var winInput = document.createElement('input');
    winInput.type = 'text';
    winInput.name = 'guidcollection';
    winInput.value = guidarray;
    win.appendChild(winInput);
    document.body.appendChild(win);
    window.open(webadress, 'Map', params);

    win.submit();
}
```

and server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (this.Request.Form.HasKeys())
    {
        object PostGuids =  this.Request.Form["guidcollection"];
        // Do something with PostGuids
    }
}
```

I still have no idea why the **HttpContext** remains undefined, but this way i can access the guid data correctly. If some one can explain that to me, i'll be glad to accept that as the answer.